# Swift: Modified hexadecimal to UINT8 with only 5 elements

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, hex, byte

I want to change from hexadecimal to `UInt8` byte. Let's say I want to change this hex `00B500000A`. Here's my current method:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var hexaData: Data { .init(hexa) }
    var hexaBytes: [UInt8] { .init(hexa) }
    private var hexa: UnfoldSequence<UInt8, Index> {
        sequence(state: startIndex) { startIndex in
            guard startIndex < self.endIndex else { return nil }
            let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 4, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex
            defer { startIndex = endIndex }
            return UInt8(self[startIndex..<endIndex], radix: 8)
        }
    }
}
```

It return this:

```
13 elements
  - 0 : 0
  - 1 : 164
  - 2 : 4
  - 3 : 0
  - 4 : 8
  - 5 : 0
  - 6 : 0
  - 7 : 0
  - 8 : 0
  - 9 : 0
  - 10 : 0
  - 11 : 0
  - 12 : 1
```

My question is, I want to change this hex `00B500000A` to `UInt8` that has only 5 elements, not 13. The result that I expected is this: `[0, 181, 0, 0, 10]`
Is it possible? How to do that in Swift? Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be almost there. Change to `offsetBy: 2` and change to `radix: 16`

Comment: @NewDev it still return 13 elements

Comment: I just tried it... so, don't know what to tell you. `offsetBy: 2` is because you need two characters, e.g. `0A` to form a byte, and `radix: 16` is because it's a hex, not octal

Comment: Ohya, just try it again and it works. Thank you for your help!